# decision tree and neural network for dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, weka, decision-tree

I am looking at what the pros and cons of using both a decision tree and a neural network for a dataset. I've been looking on the internet trying to find answers but all I seem to be finding are the pros and cons of each in the big picture. Basically I'm trying to work out why a decision tree and neural network would be good for a particular dataset. I'm assuming if the dataset is large or small, outliers, and missing data would have an effect on whether using decision trees or neural networks is accurate or less accurate. Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't really on topic for this site, but I recommend the [free Weka online courses](https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/explorer) as an introduction to how to use different classifiers in Weka and to figure out for yourself which type (and which parameters) best suit your specific data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think about the choice of machine-learning model:

1) Neural nets are the most flexible, which can be good or bad. For tasks where you have millions of training examples, a neural net will generally perform best.

2) If you have few training examples (like, maybe 10 or fewer training examples per dimension of your feature vector) then a neural net will be at risk of overfitting. A model with less flexibility, such as decision tree or naive Bayes, might do a better job. Though, you can still use a neural net in these cases if you tune metaparameters carefully to reduce overfitting.

3) If you have few training examples, AND the underlying phenomenon that you're trying to model is too complicated to model with simple decision boundaries, then none of the generic models will perform well. However, if you have a priori knowledge of the phenomenon (e.g. if you know the form of the physics equation that describes it) then you can make your own custom model, and train its unknown parameters with gradient descent.

[Andrew Ng's free machine learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) is a good resource that talks about some of the rules of thumb and intuition around overfitting and choice of model.

Comment: Thanks for the help Luke